# Angular upgrade to v15 - Routing issue from the sub application

Tags: angular-routing, angular-upgrade, nx-monorepo

I am facing a routing issue after upgrading the angular applications (monorepo  nx version 15.9.6) from v13 to v15.2.9. The entry dashboard application has 3 sub applications (vendor, item and notification).I can navigate to any of the sub applications from the dashboard (for ex. `localhost/notification-management`). But further navigation from a sub application is not working i.e. not loading the component (`localhost/notification-management/notification-creation`) instead it stays on the same page but the url got changed to (`localhost`). No error in the console, but the below warning message

`notification-management-search.component.ts:214 The navigation to / will instead go to /notification-management/notification-creation in an upcoming version of Angular.` relativeTo`might need to be removed from the`UrlCreationOptions`. warn @ core.mjs:23485 navigateByUrl @ router.mjs:5359 navigate @ router.mjs:5398 createNotification @ notification-management-search.component.ts:214 NotificationManagementSearchComponent_Template_h5_click_5_listener @ notification-management-search.component.html:10`

I tried loading the component  (`localhost/notification-management/notification-creation`) manually from the address bar - It loads as expected. No issues. There is no issue in v13, but having the issue in v15. Is there anything I am missing?

**app-routing.module.ts [dashboard]**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';
import { DashboardLandingComponent } from './core/components/landing/dashboard-landing.component';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from './core/guards/authentication.guard';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './core/components/pagenotfound/pagenotfound.component';


const DASHBOARD_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    // Route to vendor-management sub-app
  path: 'item-management',
  canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        type: 'module',
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4202/remoteEntry.js',
        exposedModule: './Module',
      })
        .then((m) => m.ItemManagementRemoteEntryModule)
        .catch((e) => console.log(e)),
  },
  {
    // Route to vendor-management sub-app
    path: 'vendor-management',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        type: 'module',
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4201/remoteEntry.js',
        exposedModule: './Module',
      })
        .then((m) => m.VendorManagementRemoteEntryModule)
        .catch((e) => console.log(e)),
  },
 {
    // Route to notification-management sub-app
    path: 'notification-management',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    loadChildren: () =>
      loadRemoteModule({
        type: 'module',
        remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:4203/remoteEntry.js',
        exposedModule: './Module',
      })
        .then((m) => m.NotificationManagementRemoteEntryModule)
        .catch((e) => console.log(e)),
  },  
  {
    // Route to Landing page
    path: '',
    component: DashboardLandingComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent,
  },
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(DASHBOARD_ROUTES, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
      enableTracing: true,
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class DashboardAppRoutingModule { }
```

**remote-entry\entry.module.ts [notification-management ]**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { NotificationManagementRemoteEntryComponent } from './entry.component';
import { NotificationManagementAppModule } from '../app.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [NotificationManagementRemoteEntryComponent],
  imports: [
    NotificationManagementAppModule,
    CommonModule],
  providers: [],
})
export class NotificationManagementRemoteEntryModule {}
```

**remote-entry\entry.component.ts [notification-management]**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'notifmgmt-entry',
  template: `<div class="remote-entry">
    <h2>notification-management's Remote Entry Component</h2>
  </div>`,
  styles: [
    `
      .remote-entry {
        background-color: #143055;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px;
      }
    `,
  ],
})
export class NotificationManagementRemoteEntryComponent {}
```

**app.module.ts - [notification-management]**

```
import { NotificationManagementRemoteEntryModule } from './remote-entry/entry.module';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NotificationManagementAppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NotificationManagementAppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { NotificationManagementCoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';






@NgModule({
  declarations: [NotificationManagementAppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    OverlayModule,
    NotificationManagementAppRoutingModule,
    NotificationManagementCoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [NotificationManagementAppComponent],
})
export class NotificationManagementAppModule {}
```

**app-routing.module.ts - [notification-management]**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NotificationManagementAppComponent } from './app.component';
const NOTIF_MANAGEMENT_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NotificationManagementAppComponent,
    children: [
     // Notification creation path
      {
        path: 'notification-creation',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../app/core/components/notification-maintenance/notification-maintenance.module').then((m) => m.NotificationMaintenanceModule)
      },


      //Edit Notification Path
      {
        path: 'edit-notification/:notificationId',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../app/core/components/notification-maintenance/notification-maintenance.module').then((m) => m.NotificationMaintenanceModule)
      },
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () =>
          import('../app/core/components/notification-search/notification-management-search.module').then((m) => m.NotificationManagementSearchModule),
      },
    ]
  },
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(NOTIF_MANAGEMENT_ROUTES)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class NotificationManagementAppRoutingModule { }
```

**notification-management-search.component.html**

```
 <h5 id="create-notification-title"
          class="tertiary-title"
          role="button"
          i18n="@@notifmgmt-search-notification-title"
          (click)="createNotification()">
        Create New Notification
  </h5>
```

**notification-management-search.component.ts**

```
public createNotification(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['notification-creation'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
```

Tried in different angular versions v14.3.0 as well, same issue.

Referred:

https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/12369

https://github.com/nrwl/nx/releases/tag/15.8.0

https://github.com/angular/angular/releases/tag/15.2.6

Tried removing the relativeTo option from router.navigate method
this.router.navigate(['notification-creation']); In this case, url in the address bar stays ``` (``localhost/notification-management``) ```) but  page is not changed. No errors or warnings.

Tried added the "/notification-management/" in router.navigate method
this.router.navigate(['/notification-management/notification-creation']); In this case, url in the address bar changed to (`localhost`) but  page is not changed. Got the below error:

`Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'notification-management/notification-creation'`

I have no issues with v13. No code change, just upgraded to v15. Is there anything I am missing? or need to be addressed differently?

Thanks